# Chimney on 100 year old home has pulled away from outside wall

Tags: brick, foundation, chimney

I am restoring a 100 year old one story wood frame home with a metal roof. The original foundation sits on cut logs. The chimney has pulled away from the roof line which leaves an exposed area where rain falls inside the exposed area. Farther down the outside wall, there is a 3 inch gap between the outside wall and the chimney. This has been like this for over 10 years.  The chimney looks straight and there are not any cracks in the brick chimney. Do you think it is the foundation of the house has sunk and this caused the house to  pull away from the chimney?  If so, should I raise the foundation? Should I remove the top of the chimney and close off the area at the top around the roof and frame up the 3 inch area at the bottom?  Should I push the chimney toward the house to close the gap?  I am doing the work myself so it needs to be something I can do on a low budget. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Need picture. In all likelihood, a solution will neither be cheap or easy.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find if the chimney is leaning or if the house is leaning.  Use a plumb bob to check - the eye can be deceiving in these situations.   The plumb bob will tell you what you should do.

In the meantime, if you wish, you could put a board or metal flashing on the gap to shed the water while you figure out what to do.

BTW... it's unlikely you could "push" the chimney towards the house as it just has too much mass.

Comment: ...not only would it be hard to push - you could literally die trying.